# Why do I get a FileNotFoundError when using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, file-not-found

My code:

```
parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
handler = WikiXmlHandler()
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
for line in subprocess.Popen(['bzcat'], 
                            stdin=open(path), 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout:
    try:
        parser.feed(line)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

The error:

```
File "c:/Users/Leon/Documents/VS Code/film.py", line 92, in <module>
    for line in subprocess.Popen(['bzcat'],
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

I do import subprocess.

The file
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py
exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `bzcat` is not in your `PATH`. It's not complaining that it can't find `subprocess.py`, it's complaining that it can't find the command you wanted to run.

Anyway, you don't need a subprocess to read `.bz2` files; see the [`bz2` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html) in the Python standard library.

```py
import bz2

with bz2.open(path, 'rt') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        parser.feed(line)
```

Like basically any compressed format, bzip2 is a binary format, so you should have used `open(path, 'rb')`. The `bz2.open()` function (slightly curiously) defaults to binary mode; if you want to read and decode as text, you have to specify `'rt'` explicitly.

Comment: I just tried to recreate this on Windows and you're right, that does seem to be the case. Do you think this might be a Windows only bug?

Comment: What bug? If they don't have `bzcat` installed that's only typical on Windows, but you'd get the same symptom on e.g. Alpine Linux if you had forgotten to install `bzcat`, or if you messed up your `PATH` so it can't be found.

Comment: What is a Windows-only bug is that you *can* pass in a string with spaces or even a list with a string with spaces with `shell=False`; but the Windows people seem to think this is a feature, not a bug.